# "export as namespace" automatically in declaration file

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a small ts library that gets outputed as UMD and I also output the *.d.ts file automatically via tsconfig: `"declaration": true`.

The file being exported looks like:

```
export class Blue { 
    alert(): void {
        console.log('alerted');
    }
}
```

Using exported UMD module declares a `window.myLib` variable.

The d.ts file looks like:

```
export declare class Blue {
    alert(): void;
}
```

Now, either via webpack, or a typescript option that I have not found I would like to also generate in the d.ts file the following line:

```
export as namespace myLib;
```

Is there a way to do this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of just:

```
export class Blue { 
    alert(): void {
        console.log('alerted');
    }
}
```

Try:

```
class Blue_ { 
  alert(): void {
      console.log('alerted');
  }
}

export { Blue_ as Blue };

declare global {
  namespace myLib {
    let Blue: typeof Blue_;
  }
}
```

This would spit the following declaration file:

```
declare class Blue_ {
    alert(): void;
}
export { Blue_ as Blue };
declare global {
    namespace myLib {
        let Blue: typeof Blue_;
    }
}
```

Now `myLib.Blue` is accessible globally, and also, `class Blue`could be imported like `import { Blue } from '...'`. Which is equivalent to having `export as namespace myLib;` in the declaration file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This solution is perfect, and it overcomes the current limitation of nested namespace in the "export as namespace" support: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20990